# C# Serialize specific property of nested object

Tags: c#, serialization, object

I have a c# object Person as a property inside another object Appointment.  My Person object has properties ID, FirstName, LastName.  I am currently serializing appointment into XML, but when it comes to the nested Person object, I would only like ID, to be serialized.  Is there a way to specify this from the Appointment class?

I simply can't go into Person and mark FirstName and LastName as non-serializable fields, because I need to serialize person in other instances within my solution.

I am hoping to find something where I can have this:

```
public class Appointment {
     [SerializeProperty("ID")]
     public Person MyPerson {
          get;
          set;
     }
```

}

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    public class Appointment
    {
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public Person MyPerson
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int MyPersonId
        {
            get { return MyPerson.Id; }
            set { MyPerson = new Person(value)}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is what I will go with.  I think it would be cool if it could be specified through an attribute, that way you didn't have to make a separate property - like MyPersonId in this case.  But it will do the trick.  Thank you -I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Person implement IXmlSerializable to do it's custom serialization (dumping only the ID, e.g.)

Or you can implement it for your Appointment instead, making it trivial to select exactly the bits you want serialized.

As a hybrid option, you can delegate the implementation of such a custom serializer to *a helper struct* that you can construct to mimick the exact serialization layout you want to have. This way, you won't have to deal with details and the XmlWriter

HTH

Comment: Thank you.  I have a custom serializer.  The problem with dumping only the ID is that I need the other properties of person to be serializable in other parts of my solution.  Thanks for the reply. :-)

Comment: So you can have the 2nd or 3rd approach - Persons will normally fully serialize, but not within Appointment? Did that help?

Comment: Yeah it helped.  Yeah I can serialize Person fully - no problem with that. I just didn't want to persist my entire nested Person object when I was serializing my appointment object.